# Preprocess daily Black Marble (VNP46A2) nighttime light product

Tags: raster, r, terra

I downloaded NASA's Black Marble daily product (VNP46A2) which is in `h5` format (the data can be dowloaded from their [website](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/search/order/1/VNP46A2--5000) (it's free you just need to create and account)). One needs to preprocess the data using the Scientific Data Sets (SDS) included in the `h5` file. Based on the [User Guide](https://viirsland.gsfc.nasa.gov/PDF/BlackMarbleUserGuide_v1.2_20210421.pdf), these are the following parameters I need to account for:

Table 4, page 14, Value of QF_Cloud_Mask in the VNP46A1/VJ146A1 product:

| Bit | Flag description key | Interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Day/night | 0 = Night |
| 4-5 | Cloud Mask Quality | 11 = High |
| 6-7 | Cloud Detection Results & Confidence Indicator | 00 = Confident Clear |
| 8 | Shadow Detected | 0 = No |
| 9 | Cirrus Detection (IR) (BTM15 – BTM16) | 0 = No Cloud |
| 10 | Snow/ Ice Surface | 0 = No Snow/Ice |

Table 7, page 17, Values of the Mandatory_Quality_Flag in VNP46A2/VJ146A2 product:

| Value | Retrieval quality | Algorithm instance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | High-quality | Main algorithm (Persistent nighttime lights) |

Table 8, page 17, Values of the Snow_Flag in VNP46A2/VJ146A2 product:

| Flag description key | Value | Interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Snow/ Ice Surface | 00 | No Snow/Ice |

In the above tables I included the bit values I want to use to preprocess the NTL product, called *Gap_Filled_DNB_BRDFCorrected_NTL*.

I am using `R`'s `terra` package to preprocess the product. So far what I have managed to do is:

```
library(terra)

wd <- "path/"

r <- rast(paste0(wd, "VNP46A2.A2018038.h28v07.001.2020333204506.h5"))

crs(r) <- "epsg:4326"

# dimensions
2400*(15/(60*60))

h = 28
v = 7

ext(r) = c(-180+h*10,-180+(h+1)*10, (8-v)*10,(8-v+1)*10) # up to this point the code works well

# the tif images inside the h5 file (for the ifel function below)
ntl <- r[[3]] # this is the Gap_Filled_DNB_BRDFCorrected_NTL
latest_high_quality_retrieval <- r[[4]]
mandatory_quality_flag <- r[[5]]
qf_cloud_mask <- r[[6]]
snow_mask <- r[[7]]

# here is the issue!!!
result <- ifel(r[[4]] > 0 & r[[5]] == 00 & r[[6]] == 1 & r[[7]] == 00, r[[3]], NA)

 # scale factor based on the User Guide table 6, page 16 
result1 <- result * 0.1

writeRaster(result1, paste0(wd, "ntl.tif"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

The `writeRaster` function returns an empty raster with null values.

I can understand how to syntax the ifel for the Mandatory_Quality_Flag and Snow_Flag but I can't understand how to syntax the bits for the QF_Cloud_Mask.

Could you help me syntax the `ifel` function properly using the bits from the tables? In a very abstract sense, the `ifel` statement should say:

```
If 
snow_flag is 00 AND 
Mandatory_Quality_Flag is 00 AND 
the bit 0 from the QF_Cloud_Mask is 0 AND 
the bit 4-5 from the QF_Cloud_Mask is  11 AND 
the bit 6-7 from the QF_Cloud_Mask is 0 AND 
the bit 8 from the QF_Cloud_Mask is  0 AND 
the bit 9 from the QF_Cloud_Mask is 0 AND 
the bit 10 from the QF_Cloud_Mask is 0 THEN 
keep the values of the Gap_Filled_DNB_BRDFCorrected_NTL ELSE 
NA
```

I noticed I shared the wrong file in my GDrive. In case someone tried to create the syntax, now the he/she can. I apologize for that.

Comment: i apologize but I don't know why the formatting of the tables isn't showing properly.

Comment: Seems the tables need a clear line before them - even though they look ok in the preview without one. Hmmm...

Comment: Oh okay thank you. In the tutorial I think they are without a line but this might be my mistake.

Comment: Do you want the solution specifically in R or Python will also work?

Comment: In R, I have zero experience with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an amazing package, called `blackmarbler` (an example can be found [here](https://worldbank.github.io/blackmarbler/)). It is easy to use, fairly straitforward and it doesn't require complex functions to georeference the h5 data. A working example taken from their website:

```
#### Setup
# Load packages
library(blackmarbler)
library(geodata)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

#### Define NASA bearer token
bearer <- "BEARER-TOKEN-HERE"

### ROI
# Define region of interest (roi). The roi must be (1) an sf polygon and (2)
# in the WGS84 (epsg:4326) coordinate reference system. Here, we use the
# getData function to load a polygon of Ghana
roi_sf <- gadm(country = "GHA", level=1, path = tempdir()) |> st_as_sf()

### Daily data: raster for February 5, 2021
r_20210205 <- bm_raster(roi_sf = roi_sf,
                        product_id = "VNP46A2",
                        date = "2021-02-05",
                        quality_flag_rm = c(1, 2), # remove the bad quality pixels
                        bearer = bearer)
```

It still uses the `raster` package instead of `terra`, it doesn't have all the Scientific Data Sets (e.g., Land/Water mask) but I spoke with the authors and their are planning to migrate to `terra` relatively soon (that was their answer).